# How can I detect if there is ( = ) sign in current line in Perl?

Tags: perl

How to detect if there is ( = ) sign in current line? thank you.

```
$_ = $currentLine;
if (Include =)
{
# do some thing
}
else
{
# do another thing
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
local $_ = $currentLine;
if (/=/) {
```

or

```
if ($currentLine =~ /=/) {
```

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is to use [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html):

```
if ( index( $line, '=' ) > -1 ) {
```

It's faster than a regex, because it's done on the C-level, without any compiliation. If you're looking in Perl code, you probably don't care if there is an equals sign on a comment line, therefore there's this:

```
$line =~ m/^[^#]*=/;
```

If that doesn't suit your needs, then use the first.

Comment: Not all `#` characters on a line denote comments. They might be embedded in strings, or they might be used as quote characters with `q##`, `s###`, and other related operators. So might `=`, for that matter.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Good point, but it's not that likely that a literal would be on the left hand side. Of course you could be assigning to `$#some_array`, which is a more likely problem. True though, that the problem is a bit more complex and a full solution for code almost requires a full parser.

Answer (score 7):

```
 my $currentLine; # presumably this has a value from something earlier

if ($currentLine =~ /=/)
{
    # line has an = in it
}
else
{
    # it doesn't
}
```

Read about the `=~` operator at [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), and regular expressions at [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reference Links.